# Ubi-partman failed with exit code 141

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install the Elementary OS on my Macbook... and...

"ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken. "

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: I found a way to solve this that worked for me, so I'm going to post my new information above my previous post.*

**New information:** After hitting the 141 error my screen stuck and I was unable to proceed forward with installation. None of the menu options worked and the only way I was able to restart the elementary installation was by pressing and holding (may 5-10 seconds) the power button.

Then rEFInd booted back up, I selected the thumb drive again and started the install from scratch using instructions from an It's F.O.S.S. guide by Abhishek Prakash (this is for Luna but worked for Freya too): http://itsfoss.com/guide-install-elementary-os-luna/

**Previous post:** I experienced this issue too installing on an old MacBook Air on a USB drive after setting up rEFInd with OS X El Capitan and partitioning the hard drive in half but leaving it blank prior to booting up Freya.

I am specifically at the Installation type stage of installation. When I click the various options (Quit, Continue anyway, Try again) there is no response and the window appears stuck.

Did you ever figure this out, OP?

Comment: Reputation points restricted me from adding more links above. 
In case it's helpful for anyone else, these other resources helped me get rEFInd in place. || http://mattjanik.ca/blog/2015/10/01/refind-on-el-capitan/ || http://themacadmin.com/mounting-the-efi-boot-partition-on-mac-os-x/ || http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/ ||